# How to select id's that have rows for all values from a set

Tags: sql

I want to select all Id from a table that have rows for both programs 'basketball' and 'football'

Given a table like this:

```
Id  program
1   basketball
2   football
3   basketball
2   basketball
1   football
4   football
5   basketball
```

How can I get a result like this:

```
id
1
2
```

Comment: SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 ;-)

Comment: Gotta ask - what's up with your ids?  Why are there repeated values?

Comment: I guess they are not primary keys.

Comment: @L-Three Regardless, those are not "identities" in any definition of the word then.

Comment: Well yes, indeed. Unless it's some kind of foreign key that identifies something else :)

Comment: These are kids Id's not a primary key in this table.

Answer (score 5):

Since you want to return the `id`'s that have both values `football` and `basketball`, you can use the following to get the result:

```
select id
from yt
where program in ('basketball', 'football')
group by id
having count(distinct program) = 2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6cedd/1).

Since can also be done by joining on your table multiple times:

```
select t1.id
from yt t1
inner join yt t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.program = 'basketball'
  and t2.program = 'football';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6cedd/3)

Answer (score 0):

I think aggregation is the most generalizable approach for this:

```
select id
from table
group by id
having sum(case when program = 'Football' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when program = 'Basketball' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

The `sum()` statement are counting the number of rows that have "football" and "basketball" respectively.  When present, the number is greater than 0.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with `IN` or `OR` syntax:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE program = 'basketball'
OR program = 'football';
```

If you want to only get the first two results, add `LIMIT 2` to the end.

By the way, it's really bad practice to have a table without a primary key, there is no way to index this table so performance would be very bad.

Comment: He may be looking for the first distinct result with each `program`. To be honest, I think he should fix his table and not repeat `id`s, and that's probably more important in terms of learning SQL than how to select distinct values (which can be easily Googled).