# PHP MySQL Group BY Having issue

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, having

Suppose I have a table like:

```
ID|Word |Reference
1 |Dog  |1
1 |Fish |2
1 |Sheep|3
2 |Dog  |4
2 |Fish |5
3 |Sheep|6
4 |Dog  |7
```

I want to select all ID's that have the word Dog ***AND*** Sheep. So the result should be ID's: 1 and 2. I tried using this query:

```
SELECT ID FROM `Table` WHERE Word='Dog' OR Word='Fish' GROUP BY ID Having Word='Dog AND Word='Fish'
```

However, this `AND` in the `Having` clause makes me get 0 results. So, am I doing something wrong or is there another way to achieve wat I want based on MySQL query only (to optimize speed, since it has to search through many rows with the same setup as in the example above)

*Basically the problem is the AND statement over multiple rows with the same ID.*

***UPDATE:***

**I need to get the reference for the ID's that where found. E.g. when the ID 1 and 2 are returned I need to know that ID 1 has reference 1 and 2. ID 2 has reference 3 and 4. Currently, I'm using this query:**

```
SELECT ID FROM `Test` WHERE Word in ('Dog', 'Fish') GROUP BY ID HAVING  count(DISTINCT Word) = 2;
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, explain why this query would not give me back ID's 3 and 4 (which are not wanted)

Comment: Same question, why would this not return the ID's 3 and 4?

Comment: Having doesn't work the way you seem to have typed it. Just leave off the having and you'll get what you want.

Comment: @Dysmondad, also for you the question why would it not return ID 3 and 4 to me when I chunk of the Having part?

Comment: @nogad, I created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddecc6). As you can see, it will also return the ID 3 because it contains the word Dog which is unwanted behavior

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select id's that have rows for all values from a set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193387/how-to-select-ids-that-have-rows-for-all-values-from-a-set)

Comment: @Don'tPanic, Great your link gave me the documentation I needed with the Having distinct statement! Thanks very much

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I updated my question, could you help me with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for my problem is solved using underneath query:

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(Reference) as ReferencesGrouped FROM `Test` WHERE Word in ('Dog', 'Fish') GROUP BY ID HAVING  count(DISTINCT Word) = 2;
```

This will return me:

```
ID|ReferencesGrouped
1 |1,4
2 |4,5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions that return the correct records, the first as individual records by ID and Reference, and the second with one record per ID and the Words and References as comma separated in columns.

**Setup table and populate rows:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `list1`;

CREATE table `list1` (
    id int(10),
    Word varchar(10),
    Reference int(10) 
);

INSERT INTO `list1` (`ID`, `Word`, `Reference`) 
VALUES 
(1, 'Dog',1),
(1 ,'Fish',2),
(1 ,'Sheep',3),
(2 ,'Dog',4),
(2 ,'Sheep',5),
(3 ,'Sheep',6),
(4 ,'Dog',7);
```

**Returns one row for each combination of ID and Word**

```
SELECT 
    t.`ID`,
    t.`Word`,
    t.`Reference`
FROM `list1` as t
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        t1.`ID` as `ref_id`
    FROM `list1` AS t1
    WHERE `Word` in ('Sheep','Dog')
    GROUP BY t1.`ID`
    HAVING count(DISTINCT t1.`Word`) = 2
) AS ts
ON t.`ID` = ts.`ref_id`
WHERE t.`Word` in ('Sheep','Dog')
ORDER BY t.`ID`,t.`Word`;
```

**Results**

```
ID  |   Word    |   Reference   
1   |   Dog     |   1
1   |   Sheep   |   3
2   |   Dog     |   4
2   |   Sheep   |   5
```

**Returns one row per ID, with a comma separated list of Words in one column, and a comma separated list of Reference in another.**

```
SELECT 
    t.`ID`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.`Word`) AS `Words`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.`Reference`) AS `References`
FROM `list1` as t
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        t1.`ID` as `ref_id`
    FROM `list1` AS t1
    WHERE `Word` in ('Sheep','Dog')
    GROUP BY t1.`ID`
    HAVING count(DISTINCT t1.`Word`) = 2
) AS ts
ON t.`ID` = ts.`ref_id`
WHERE t.`Word` in ('Sheep','Dog')
GROUP BY t.`ID`
ORDER BY t.`ID`,t.`Word`;
```

**Results:**

```
ID  |   Words       |   References  
1   |   Dog,Sheep   |   1,3
2   |   Dog,Sheep   |   4,5
```

Comment: Great approach, how will it influence performance? The join seems killing to me on large tables? Say 500k rows and selecting e.g. 4 words makes it join 4 identical tables of 500k rows each...

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren, for 4 keywords, you wouldn't join on 4 tables. You just add the terms to the two lists and change 2 to 4.

Comment: I see however than I could fit it in one query. No need for the inner join than

Comment: Do you have a unique index on Words and References? If not, and a Word + Reference are duplicated, your query will fail to produce accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the table on itself. This way you can pick up where the id's are the same for instances where dog and sheep overlap.
Try this:

```
declare @t table (id int ,  Word varchar(10) )
insert into @t (ID, Word) values (1, 'Dog'),
(1 ,'Fish'),
(1 ,'Sheep'),
(2 ,'Dog'),
(2 ,'Sheep'),
(3 ,'Sheep'),
(4 ,'Dog')

select t.ID
from @t as t
join @t as t1 on t1.id = t.id
where t.word = 'Dog' and t1.word = 'Sheep'
```

Comment: For you the same question, please explain why this query would not return the ID's 3 and 4... Distinct will only check that the ID only appears once in the result set (as far as I know). This means that it will return all the ID's stated above, since each ID has the word Dog OR Fish...?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren, you are correct. I have since corrected my answer. Thank you for keeping me honest.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it by joining your table to itself.

```
SELECT t1.id FROM `Table` t1
INNER JOIN `Table` t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.word='Dog' AND t2.word='Sheep';
```

Comment: That's a great idea, however how much will this influence the performance? For each extra word I have to join the table. Say I'm looking for 5 words than I have to join 4 tables to the original table...?

Comment: I found an answer that shows another way to do it. Unfortunately it appears to be on a duplicate of this question.